# Cannot convert Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> to JsonObject in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, testing, serialization

I am trying to return JsonObject as the interface of my method is -
`public Task<ServiceResult<JsonObject>> GetTranslation(string language);` but my test fails at expectedData:

```
  var apiResponse = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>() 
      {
        { "PAGE_NAME", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "KEY_NAME", "LOCALE IN PARAMETER LANGUAGE" }, { "COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD", "Copy to clipboard" } } }
      };

      var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse);
      var expectedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObject>(jsonString);
```

`Error Message: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Unable to find a default constructor to use for type System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject. Path 'PAGE_NAME', line 1, position 13.`

I can't change the interface as it can't deserialize the returned object.

Comment: You serialized a "Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>" so deserialize into that type also and not a JsonObject. Besides that you mixed up to different JsonSerializers  either use Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json.

Comment: `JsonObject` is a *parsed* representation of text in JSON format. Parsing something is not the same as deserializing it.

Comment: Yes, it works that way but I want to deserialize it into a JsonObject because the interface returns that type. If I deserialize it to Dictionary again the next line fails.
 var serviceMock = new Mock<ITranslationService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        serviceMock
            .Setup(s => s.GetTranslation(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(expectedData);

ITranslationService declares 
public Task<ServiceResult<JsonObject>> GetTranslation(string language);

Comment: Deserializing JSON text into `JsonObject` makes no sense. You need to parse it: `JsonObject.Parse(jsonString)`.

Comment: Don't get it. Can you rephrase your question a bit to clarify? if you mock something that returns a JsonObject why do you try to serialize and deserialize something? That something that presumably happens already in the real implementation but here just return a JsonObject and let the code under test do whatever it needs to do with the JsonObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply parsing the JSON string:

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

// ...

var expectedData = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString)!.AsObject();
```

Comment: Thank youuuu! Works that way!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend two options,

Option 1 :

Create the Json object as class - you can convert using online Json to c# convertors or Paste your Json as C# using Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON as C# (in Visual Studio), created below classes based on your sample provided.

```
public class PAGENAME
{
    public string KEY_NAME { get; set; }
    public string COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public PAGENAME PAGE_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

Post that in the *DeserializeObject* , we should use Root class

```
var apiResponse = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
  {
    { "PAGE_NAME", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "KEY_NAME", "LOCALE IN PARAMETER LANGUAGE" }, { "COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD", "Copy to clipboard" } } }
  };

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse);
        var expectedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Option 2:

Use *JObject* from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

```
var expectedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
```

The exact error is because JsonObject doesn't have any default constructors.